# Calendar view ignores custom content type list forms

Tags: content-type, calendar, custom-form

I have a Calendar list 'EventCalendar'. The list uses two custom content types; both independently based on the base Event content type. I removed the default 'Event' content type, and replaced it with my own custom content type, 'Event Cal Event', which I set as default for the list. This content type uses DispForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx, NewForm.aspx for the forms. All three of those forms have been modified, but I stuck with the default naming, and they are tagged as the defaults for the list. I have an additional content type 'Event Cal Registration Event', uses similarly customized forms, named DispRegForm.aspx, EditRegForm.aspx, NewRegForm.aspx. In the content type itself, I've updated the forms for this content type to point to 'Lists/EventCalendar/DispRegForm.aspx' and so on.

In my EventCalendar list, I have added events based on both content types. When picking "New > (content type name)" from the Ribbon and adding events that way, the correct content type form is diaplayed, and I can add events fine.

When viewing the EventCalendar list using the "All Events" view, clicking on a event displays the corresponding DispForm.aspx or DispRegForm.aspx page.

The trouble for me is, the Calendar View view, which is what most folks want to see, is ignoring those custom forms, and is always using the DispForm.aspx form, regardless of the content type. If I'm looking at the Calendar View, and mouse over an event created using the "Event Calendar Registration Event" content type, the URL shown in the toolbar is "DispForm.aspx?ID=10" or so forth. I have tried defining a new Calendar View instead of the default, bbut this same behavior continues.

While I suspect the calendar view could be bludgeoned with jQuery, the performance hit would likely be unacceptable. I'm already using Visual Studio 2010 on other parts of this site collection, so using VS2010 is a possiblity should it be necessary.

Google has not at all been my friend. Useful information on custom content type forms is just not out there. Does anybody have a suggestion or answer on how to get the Calendar View to correctly reference the correct custom content type display form, the way the "All Items" view does? Fwiw, this is SP2010 Server.

Comment: I'm having the same issues. Have you found a solution or workaround with this?

Comment: No I have not. Sorry.